# JavaScript line with semicolon behaving strange

Tags: javascript

I am facing a strange issue with this code. I can fix it easily but I would like to know why this is happening.

If I comment out `child` below I get `undefined` error in IFFY. The function is located in global scope and should work everywhere. Not sure why?

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cgw1dpmg/3/)

```
parent=function(){   
    parent.prototype.method1= function() {}
    parent.prototype.property = true;
}

child=function() {
    parent.call(this);    
    child.prototype = new parent(); 
}

child; // This is important, if I remove this, I get an undefined error in IFFY ?


(function(){
    var instance1 = new child();
    console.log( instance1 );  // Empty Object

    var instance2 = new child();
    console.log( instance2 ); // Object is not empty

}());
```

(there are also [other issues with this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31100648/1048572) which I asked about in an extra question)

Comment: You probably meant to manipulate each "type"s `prototype` outside the function. It will probably solve your problems

Comment: @Amit I know it fixes it but why this particular behaviour?

Comment: This is just automatic semicolon insertion messing with you. Watch those semicolons.

Comment: Are you aware that the `parent.prototype` property refers to the prototype used when instantiating a new object with `new parent()`, and NOT the actual prototype of the instance itself? In order to access the actual prototype you'd need to use Object.getPrototypeOf(), or the (non-standard) `__proto__` property.

Comment: @JS-JMS-WEB because the function itself is defining the Constructor. The prototype is defined based off of the Constructor.

Answer (score 4):

This is just automatic semicolon insertion messing with you. When you omit the `child` you get:

```
child=function() {
    parent.call(this);    
    child.prototype = new parent(); 
}

(function(){
    var instance1 = new child();
    console.log( instance1 );  // Empty Object

    var instance2 = new child();
    console.log( instance2 ); // Object is not empty

}());
```

Which is parsed as:

```
child=function() {
    parent.call(this);    
    child.prototype = new parent(); 
}(function(){ // FUNCTION CALL
    var instance1 = new child();
    console.log( instance1 );  // Empty Object

    var instance2 = new child();
    console.log( instance2 ); // Object is not empty
}());
```

Comment: But I get the similar result when I do `var parent=function(){   
    parent.prototype.method1= function() {}
    parent.prototype.property = true;
},  child=function() {
    child.prototype = new parent(); 
};new child(); // normal new child(); //parent's prototype`

Comment: "if I remove this, I get an undefined error in IFFY ?" my answer solves _that part_.