# Javascript prototypal inheritance and new keyword

Tags: javascript

Code snippet below gives different output for two instances of same constructor (Child). First object(instance1) is without prototype and second(instance2) is with prototype, why?

```
   parent=function(){   
        parent.prototype.method1= function() {}
        parent.prototype.property = true;
    };

    child=function() {
        parent.call(this);    
        child.prototype = new parent(); 
    };

    (function(){
        var instance1 = new child();
        console.log( instance1 );  // Empty Object

        var instance2 = new child();
        console.log( instance2 ); // Object is not empty

    }());
```

**Output:**

[image]

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cgw1dpmg/4/)

Comment: Because you must not overwrite `.prototype` inside of the constructor! The instance has already been created and the prototype chain has been set up in there.

Comment: Btw, you [should not use `new parent` to create prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here)